# LinearLayout as clickable in fragment java cannot resolve method findViewById

Tags: java, android, fragment

Hey guys I've been building my own app for my project in that I created fragments in one of my fragment I need to set a value by clicking a whole linear layout.

But when I done that I got error in fragment java code `findViewById` (**cannot resolve method `findViewById(init)`**).

I'm stuck at this please help I'm in hurry!!

Here's my code under OnCreateView

```
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);
       LinearLayout set = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
       return view;
```

Comment: Use `view.findViewById()`

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass view when working in your **fragment**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);
LinearLayout set = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your code to:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);
LinearLayout set = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
return view;
```

as you are getting your view in variable `view` so you have to find it from the view only.

Answer (score 1):

In fragment,you can just call your view instead of calling your Linear Layout id,

```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);
   LinearLayout set = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
   return view;
```